# python: [try + except] How to make sure all command under try is executed?

Tags: python

This is a very beginners' question. But I cannot find answer...

I want to run **ALL** lines under `try`. If **ANY** lines are unexecutable, run `except`.

For example, I have some codes like this...

```
for i in range(0,100):
    try:
        print "a"
        print "b"
        print i, C
        print "d"
    except:
        print i, "fail"
```

I want to have **ALL** the lines under `try` executed. In this example, `print C` is unexecutable, because `C` is not pre-defined.

Thus, I want to **ONLY** run `print i, "fail"` under `except`, because `NOT ALL` lines under `try` are executable.

To be more clearly, The code above gives me the result:

```
a
b
0 0 Fail
a
b
1 1 Fail
a
b
2 2 Fail
...
```

But I want to have a result like this:

```
0 Fail
1 Fail
2 Fail
...
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
To be more clearly, I am not asking for a result, I am asking for a method. I think there should be some commands to control `try`.

Comment: So, even if the first two lines in the try are fine, if the line fails, you don't want to show those two successful lines, but rather just the exception when you call that method?

Comment: Write try catch for each of the prints then :)

Comment: @idjaw, yes, that is what I want to.

Comment: With the example in your question you can just do what trincot's answer suggests. But in general, what you want is not possible: either you need a time machine, or you'd need to analyse the later statements to see what they'd do before you execute the earlier statements. And due to the [Halting Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), that analysis may take forever.

Comment: Are you asking about [transactional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing) behaviour? I don't think this is generally possible, since Python will only know whether something is executeable by executing it. You could solve your problem by defining different _actions_, though, each with a _do_ and _undo_ method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could temporarily redirect stdout and only print in the except:

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO


for i in range(0,100):
    sys.stdout = StringIO()
    try:
        print "a"
        print "b"
        print i, C
        print "d"
    except Exception as e:
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        print i, "fail" # or print e
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Which would give you:

```
0 fail
1 fail
2 fail
3 fail
4 fail
5 fail
6 fail
7 fail
8 fail
9 fail
10 fail
11 fail
12 fail
13 fail
14 fail
15 fail
16 fail
17 fail
18 fail
19 fail
20 fail
21 fail
22 fail
23 fail
24 fail
25 fail
26 fail
27 fail
28 fail
29 fail
30 fail
31 fail
32 fail
33 fail
34 fail
35 fail
36 fail
37 fail
38 fail
39 fail
40 fail
41 fail
42 fail
43 fail
44 fail
45 fail
46 fail
47 fail
48 fail
49 fail
50 fail
51 fail
52 fail
53 fail
54 fail
55 fail
56 fail
57 fail
58 fail
59 fail
60 fail
61 fail
62 fail
63 fail
64 fail
65 fail
66 fail
67 fail
68 fail
69 fail
70 fail
71 fail
72 fail
73 fail
74 fail
75 fail
76 fail
77 fail
78 fail
79 fail
80 fail
81 fail
82 fail
83 fail
84 fail
85 fail
86 fail
87 fail
88 fail
89 fail
90 fail
91 fail
92 fail
93 fail
94 fail
95 fail
96 fail
97 fail
98 fail
99 fail
```

But there are no doubt much better ways to do whatever it is you are trying to do in your real logic.

Bar seeing into the future you cannot print in real time if all calls are going to be successful as you have not seen them all so you would need to store the output and see if there were any errors.

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO

stdo = StringIO()
errs = False
for i in range(0, 100):
    sys.stdout = stdo
    try:
        print "a"
        print "b"
        print i
        print "d"
    except Exception as e:
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        errs = True
        print i, "fail"
        sys.stdout = stdo

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
if not errs:
    print(stdo.getvalue())
```

Any error will show in real time but you will have to wait until the end to see if all are successful.

Comment: But it doesnot work, if I change 'print i, C' to 'print i'.

Comment: I like the solution but you need to print in the success case also

Comment: If there are no errors, I want to have the correct result. :-) like always.

Comment: @doglas, that involves storing all the results similar to the logic in the other answer and checking if there were no errors which we could implement pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you so much! I dont have problem to wait. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could alter the code so that it only prints when all expressions are valid:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    try:
        print ("a" + "\n" +
               "b" + "\n" + 
               C   + "\n" +
               "d")
    except:
        print (i, "fail")
```

Another variation to the same principle uses a list to store the things to be printed if all is successful:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    try:
        collect = []
        collect.append("a")
        collect.append("b")
        collect.append(C)
        collect.append("d")
        print("\n".join(collect))
    except:
        print (i, "fail")
```

Comment: No, no. you misunderstand me. I want to have a more general method.

Comment: Well, you should update your question then, because this gives exactly the output you asked for.

Comment: It's like I have a lot of lines under try, I cannot combine them into one line.

Comment: But you can concatenate each value to a string in each line and print only when that string is complete, no?

Comment: I added a variation of the code. The principle is that you should somehow delay the printing, and instead collect what you want to print, to only print it after all your `try` code succeeded.

Comment: I am not asking for a result, I am asking for a method. I think there should be some commands to control try.

Comment: You'll have to define *control try* a bit more clearly: you cannot expect statements that have already been executed successfully to be magically "undone" when an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to what @trincot posted, not sure if it would meet your requirements.

Basically, move all of your prints to a separate function and call that in your try.

```
def printer(i=None, C=None):
    print "a"
    print "b"
    print i, C
    print "d"    

for i in range(0,100):
    try:
        printer(i, C)
    except:
        print i, "fail"
```

Comment: This works for the (rather artificial) case of undefined variables, but for any other runtime exception that occurs within the function, it will just run part of the function and then except.

Comment: @tobias_k You are correct, thanks for pointing that out. Maybe a better solution would be to gather the text in a variable and return that to be printed. Or just run the code trincot posted. If the end goal for this code is different than just printing, it may be useful to break it into separate function(s).